# Compensating clock drift "by hand" - what have I solved?

Tags: clock, midi, synchronization

**Edit: I'm not actually looking for a *solution*, because short of syncing the hardware clocks (which I can't do) there isn't one. What I'm looking for is an *explanation* of where the magic -8.4ms I seem to have identified is coming from.**

I have a hardware music sequencer (Squarp Pyramid), a laptop, a digital MIDI-triggered drum synthesizer (Roland TR-8), and an audio mixing console with built-in USB audio (Soundcraft Signature 12 MTK). Using my laptop with DAW software (Reaper), I record a sequence of drum beats from the TR-8, triggered over hardware MIDI from the Pyramid:

[image: Audio setup]

What I find is that the beat-markers in Reaper drift over time compared to the onsets of beats in the recorded audio - between 10ms and 20ms per minute of audio, depending on the BPM. This is expected, of course, but I'd like to reduce it as much as possible.

I don't have access to a reliable way of keeping the clocks in sync. The solution I'm working with right now is to use a slightly modified BPM on Reaper to compensate for the drift. For example, for 125BPM on the Pyramid, I set reaper to 125.02BPM. For 117BPM on the Pyramid, I set Reaper to 117.0382BPM. This reduces the drift to fractions of ms per minute of recorded audio, which I can live with - but I have to work out the drift by hand, and it's different for each BPM.

My method for determining the drift amount is as follows:

1. Record 10 minutes of audio with beat pulses at a particular BPM.
2. Align the onset of the 0th recorded audio beat with t=0 in Reaper.
3. Find the nearest Reaper beat marker to t=10mins, and measure the distance between it and the onset of the corresponding audio beat. This distance represents the clock drift over 10 minutes.

[image: 95ms clock drift over 10 minutes at 125bpm]
[image: Negligable clock drift over 10 minutes at 125.02bpm]

For 125BPM, the drift over 10 minutes is -95ms, giving me -9.5ms of drift per minute. \$\frac{60000}{59990.5}*125 = 125.02\$, so I set Reaper to 125.02BPM and the drift over 10 minutes becomes small enough to not be a problem any more. Unfortunately this has to be re-calculated for every BPM I set on the Pyramid. I figured out I can streamline this process by writing a C++ app that uses the RtMidi library to sample incoming MIDI clock pulses from the Pyramid’s USB output, calculating a rolling offset error to estimate drift from an expected BPM.

[image: USB sampling setup]

For 125BPM, the USB samples exhibit a clock drift of -1.1ms per minute, and I have to add a magic number of -8.4ms of drift per minute to match what I'm seeing when I line things up by hand in Reaper. I've tried this across multiple BPMs and the -8.4ms seems consistent (+/- 0.2ms). This method gives me reliable predictions for a BPM to use in Reaper to get the beat marks to line up with the audio, but the -8.4ms magic number is troubling.

Where is this magic -8.4ms coming from? I figure there are three clocks involved:

1. Pyramid (P)
2. My laptop (L)
3. The USB audio module in the mixing console (M)

I suppose that the tweaked BPM in Reaper needs to be based on *driftPM* (clock drift between Pyramid and mixer's USB audio). My USB capture method is giving me *driftPL*. The magic -8.4ms must then be *driftLM*. So *driftPM = driftPL + driftLM*.

**Does this seem correct?** It appears to work in practise but I feel like I’m stabbing in the dark. **Is there an easier approach?**

Comment: you need a realtime kernel on pc, before taking any conclusons.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič for brevity I didn't clarify, but my estimation method of USB sampling + magic -8.4ms reproduced observations accurately (+/- 0.2ms drift per minute) in 6/6 verification cases, and was able to accurately predict 2/2 test cases.

Comment: you could draw a block diagram with circuit lab. it's not clear how do you measure and what peripheral io type you measure: midi pulses, wav file, ...etc

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I added a couple of images and clarified how I'm sampling the USB midi - does this help?

Comment: Sorry, no. USB is USB and MIDI is MIDI. I had never heard about USB-MIDI, maybe I am wrong, but still MIDI outputs sequence of pulses, which is a code. Your picture shows some analog signal.

Comment: If your sequence repeats every bar just record one bar's worth and place multiple copies on each bar start in reaper. No need to record a full length repetitive audio file when it's likely that most of the piece of music has the same beat sequence repeated throughout.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Ah, of course. For brevity I edited out the mention of the drum machine but didn't realise that could've been confusing. I've added a diagram at the top to illustrate the recording setup.

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately, the sequences aren't repetitive. the basic beat is just for testing. it's important for my use-case that I can maintain less than a few ms of drift over at least 5 minutes.

Comment: With all due respect I don't see how this question fits into the EE.SE

Comment: @Vinzent fair enough, but can you suggest where else it might go? I'm helping to find an answer from someone knowledgeable about clock drift on digital systems - it's probably too EE for software folks, and it's perhaps too software engineering for synth/music folks.

Comment: @damian The way I see it the (only) electrical engineering solution is to synchronize the clocks in HW. If that is not an option then I don't see what the electrical engineering aspect of a solution would be. But I don't want to be a buzzkill if other people here can (and want to) be helpful then great! (:.

Comment: @Vinzent right - I'm not actually looking for an EE *solution*, I'm looking for an EE *explanation* of where the magic -8.4ms is coming from. Sorry if that's not clear.

Comment: I don't know where your specific drift of -8.4ms comes from, but I came to think of something else which might be of use to you; Clock frequency can be (is usually) highly influenced by the temperature inside your devices. Perhaps you could experiment with cooling and/or heating the different devices in order to get their clock frequencies to be in sync and stable :P. I know it's a bit out there but well..

Comment: [Pyramid](https://squarp.net/PYRAMiDi.pdf) docs mention an "clock auto slave sync". So if you could feed a MIDI sync signal, it probably can synchronize to something else (note I know nothing about MIDI). Generating this is another story, unless the mixer can output it, or some other kind of timing signal, master clock, SPDIF, whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequencer and soundcard clocks come from crystal oscillators.

8.4ms/min is a 140ppm difference in frequency, which is a bit high but not impossible, for example if both use 100ppm accuracy crystals and you get a bit unlucky.

It probably depends on temperature too, so if the temperatures of the sequencer and the USB soundcard inside the mixer vary, your "magic" -8.4ms/min may change.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. I really hope it doesn't change enough to mess up all my work from the past day!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that lies entirely within the Reaper software itself. Its "BPM estimator" algorithm has limited resolution, mainly due to the fact that it makes its estimate over a time interval that is much shorter than 10 minutes(!).

It then tries to round its result to a "reasonable" number, such as an integer number of BPM. But as [peufeu says](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452772/11683), it's using the computer timebase as a reference, which is not linked in any way to the original Pyramid sequencer timebase. Even if both are crystal-controlled, a 140-ppm total error is not outside the realm of possibility.

This sort of issue is exactly why music studios, etc. use a "global clock" or "house clock" to synchronize all of the equipment together.

Comment: I'm not actually using Reaper's "BPM estimator" (I assume you mean the thing that is supposed to sync Reaper to incoming MIDI time code pulses?)